# How to set up the Ant-Design 'Select' component dropdown box to scroll laterally

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

The content of the drop-down box can be scrolled laterally if it is too long

The Ant-Design version: 4.1.5

I set the dropdownStyle in the document and it doesn't work

```
<Select
  dropdownStyle={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}
>
  // Options...
<
```

I also tried to set the dropdownClassName

It didn't work

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this CSS should be working

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  overflow: initial;
}
```